What is the use of these 2 rubber rings in a threadless steel headset and how is the top ring positioned?
I have this type of headset

(The above image I found in the internet. But it corresponds to what I have. It has a ball bearing ring and not a cartridge bearing.)
Both part 1 and 2 are rubber.
Part 1 is visible when everything is installed. Part 1 is not flush with the top of part 3. That is part 1 does not completely sit inside the top of part 3.
Part 2 is hidden under part 3.
Here pictures from the actual bicycle. Part 1 is visible. But part 2 is hidden under part 3.


Questions

What is the purpose of parts 1 and 2?
Is it fine that part 1 does not sit flush inside the top of part 3?
Because part 1 is rubber and sticking out above part 3, will there always be a small amount of visible play between the headset and the headtube (i.e. play between part 3 and part 4) when rocking the bicycle and pulling the front brake?


Is there some kind of tape on your head tube? What is the carbon fiber looking tube on top of the handlebar stem?

I put duck tape on the head tube to protect against rubbing from the brake and gear cables. The handlebar stem is long (it has not been cut down). Above the stem are plastic spacers (3 spacers, only 2 visible on the photos).

If I'm understanding correctly,

The rubber parts (part 1 and 2) are barriers against dirt and other contaminates.

It is OK that the top seal (part 2) is visible.

A correctly adjusted headset will spin smoothly and have no play.


